# How to make first letter in search field Uppercase in Vue

Tags: vue.js

How do I make the first letter in search form an uppercase, Your help will be appreciated.

Below is the code snippet. It's giving an error "Expecting a string or number but array given".

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchForm',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
      return {
          searchString: ''
      }
  },
  methods: {
      parseSearchString() {
          // Trim search string
          const trimmedSearchString = this.searchString.trim()

          if(trimmedSearchString !== '') {

              // Split search string
              const searchParams = trimmedSearchString.split(/\s+/)

               //Uppercase search string
              searchParams.split(' ')
                  .map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1))
                  .join('<br>');

              // Emit event
              this.$emit('search', searchParams)

              // Reset input field
              this.searchString = []
          }
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Have you try to clear your searchString with empty string nor empty array?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but I'm getting searchParam is not a function.

Comment: searchParam or searchString?